# html div, tags dont work after Header()?

Tags: php, html

I need help. Are html tags and divs and something in html loading after Header send ?
I try this bud after header the div yes dont show...

```
Header("Location: index.php");
Echo "<div class=\"yes\">Some text will release</div>";
```

Is there any way to reload page and code will working with html after ?

The yes div is message If the code will work for example:

```
<div class=\"yes\">Succesfull</div>
```

Thank for help

Thanks for all help I got Idea:

On the firt page:

```
Header("Location: index.php&successfull=1");
```

On the second page:

```
If (IsSet($_GET['successfull'])) {
    If ($_GET['successfull'] == "1") { Echo "<div class=\"yes\">Successfull</div>"; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're saying to go to a different page, so no, you can't echo more HTML. You can however send that message to the next page via the $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is redirecting to another page. The code you are echoing is being output to the browser, but you don't see it because the redirect occurs

Comment: I reloading the some page.. that index is for example :)

Comment: If that is the case, then you should end up in a redirect loop (unless there is more code than what you are showing).

Answer (score 0):

the echo you have after the header wont show since you first redirect to another page.

Comment: @Machete You could use Javascript timer script to delay the redirect. So you will first show the echo you want to. and after n seconds you will redirect to the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Location` says "The page you are asking for isn't here, go to this other place to get it instead".

In general, there is no way for an HTTP header to tell the browser to reload the page. You can only send an HTTP response header in reply to an HTTP request… and if you get an HTTP request, then the page is being reloaded already.

The exception is when it is responding to a request with an `If-Modified-Since` header.

You may wish to have a read of [the mnot caching tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) which explains how to tell browsers when they should get a fresh copy of a page instead of loading it from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

you cant preview html code because the page will reload to index.php
so use

```
<?
header("location:index.php");
?>
<div class="yes">Some text will release</div>
```

Or keep

```
<div class="yes">Some text will release</div>
```

For the next page

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna see the html output you can use this

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5; URL=index.php">
<div class="yes">Some text will release</div>
```

and change Content="5 to the number of second that will wait

Answer (score 0):

You have to use meta-refresh instead:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=index.php" />
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class=\"yes\">Succesfull</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will display the message for 3 seconds.